# Mongoose $inc operation error on a nested document

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema:

```
const postsStatsSchema = new Schema({
    postid: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: [128, "post ID must be at most 128"],
        required: true
    },
    likecounter: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        min: 0,
        required: true
    }
});

const userStatsSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: [50, "Name length must be at most 50"]
    },
    posts: {
        type: [postsStatsSchema],
        required: true
    }
});

const statisticsSchema = new Schema({
    month: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    users: {
        type: [userStatsSchema],
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

I'm trying to increment (or create, if the document does not exist) the 'likecounter' in the postsStats object. I tried many different ways, but non were successful. This is the last thing I tried:

```
let update = {};
update['$inc'] = {};
update['$inc'] = {'users.$.username.user.$.posts.somepost.likecounter': 1000};

try {
    const res = await stats.findOneAndUpdate({month: 100}, update, {'upsert': true});
    console.log(res);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

The error I'm getting on the code above is:

```
 MongoError: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path
```

I tried many variations, with and without the '$' sign, but only managed to increment the month. I believe it is something with the nested document that Im doing wrong but just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: `users.$.username` is defined as a String. What do you expect `users.$.username.user` to be?